# How to submit an argument to keyword proof?

Tags: isabelle

I would like to understand how keyword `proof` works in an Isar proof. I consulted [the Isabelle/Isar reference, section 6.3.2](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf#page=130) and [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL, section 4.1](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/prog-prove.pdf#page=42).

To summarise what I have learned, there are three ways of beginning a proof by the keyword `proof`:

- without any argument Isabelle finds a suitable introduction rule to the lemma being proved and applies it in a forward mode
- if a hyphen: `-` is supplied as an argument, then `proof` does nothing to the goal, avoiding any automatic rule being applied when it would lead to a blind alley
- if a specific rule, like `rule name`, `unfold true_def`, `clarify` or `induct n` is supplied, then it is applied to the goal in a forward mode

Am I right that the third case is like using `apply` with the argument supplied?

How is the automatic introduction rule in the first case picked by the system?

And, does the above fully describe the usage of `proof`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `proof` without a method specification applies the method `default`. The method `default` is almost like `rule`, but if `rule` fails, then it tries next `intro_classes` and then `unfold_locales`. The method `rule` without being given a list of theorems tries all rules that are declared to the classical reasoner (`intro`, `elim`, and `dest`). If no facts are chained in, only `intro` rules are considered. Otherwise, all types of rules are tried. All chained-in facts must unify with the rules. `dest` rules are transformed into `elim` rules before they are applied.

You can print all declared rules with `print_rules`. Safe rules (`intro!`, `elim!`, ...) are preferred over normal rules (`intro`, `elim`, ...) and extra rules (`intro?`, `elim?`) come last.

You can also use `rule` without giving any rules. Then, it behaves like `default`, but without the fallbacks `intro_classes` and `unfold_locales`.

Answer (score 1):

Andreas gave a good description of how `proof` without a method argument works; I'll just cover some other parts of the question.

First, `proof (method)` is like `apply (method)` except for one thing: While `apply` leaves you in "prove" mode, where you can continue with more `apply` statements, `proof` transitions into "state" mode, where you must use a `have` or `show` statement to continue proving. Otherwise the effect on the goal state is the same.

I'd also like to point out that case 2 (`proof -`) is really an instance of case 3, because `-` is actually an ordinary proof method just like `rule name` or `induct` (you can also write `apply -`, for example). The hyphen `-` proof method does nothing, except that it will insert chained facts into the current goal, if it is given any chained facts.

Comment: What are chained facts?